# Error when trying to load data from an OData Source Editor to a SQL db table

Tags: sql, ssis

Several Errors of the same type when trying to load a SQL db table from an OData SharePoint connection.

[GFXBankAccountProcessing - DB GFX Account List [2]] Error: An error occurred while setting up a binding for the "BLCompanyID" column. The binding status was "DT_NTEXT". The data flow column type is "DBBINDSTATUS_UNSUPPORTEDCONVERSION". The conversion from the OLE DB type of "DBTYPE_IUNKNOWN" to the destination column type of "DBTYPE_WVARCHAR" might not be supported by this provider.

It is expected to load the table and proceed to the next function within the process. I believe it has something to do with the data conversion but I am not sure what to convert the data to. I have looked to try to compare datatypes that the table in the DB is requiring. It is a NVARCHAR but I am not sure why it would fail. BLCompanyID is only one column, some of the other columsn are succedding while that one and a few others are failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the data type you are trying to store into the destination table is not the correct format. For instance, if the destination table requires an nvarchar(255) and you're trying to insert a DT_NTEXT, it will fail. You will need to convert the column to DT_WSTR with a length of 255.

Here's a quick reference that I have bookmarked to help me:
http://wiki.melissadata.com/index.php?title=FAQ%3ASSIS%3AData_Type_Conversions